# Issue with jQuery script Getting jQuery(...).onclick is not a function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a script to work, I got it working in a JSFiddle. I keep getting a TypeError and I'm not sure what's going on. The script is below.

Yes, jQuery and jQuery noConflict are being loaded before this.

```
 jQuery(".icon").onclick(
 function(){
  var tab = jQuery(this).attr("data-tab");
     if( jQuery(".visible").attr("data-tab") != tab ){
          jQuery(".visible").removeClass("visible");
                                                }
     jQuery(".content[data-tab='" + tab + "']").toggleClass("visible");
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick` is not a jQuery function. You need to use `.on('click', function() {....`:

```
jQuery(".icon").on('click', function() {

    var tab = jQuery(this).attr("data-tab");

    if (jQuery(".visible").attr("data-tab") != tab) 
    {
        jQuery(".visible").removeClass("visible");
    }

    jQuery(".content[data-tab='" + tab + "']").toggleClass("visible");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that got rid of the error, but it doesn't seem to be working, but that's a different issue.